# Login redirect after blocked content

Tags: joomla3.0

I have some articles that are not accessible to non-registered users. When they press the link it prompts them to login, but after a successful login they are sent to their profile. Instead I want them to be sent to the target article after login. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default login specified in your Administration back end from your custom code you can do so with the following:

Take the url that you would like to redirect the user to after they have successfully logged in and apply the 'base64_encode' function to it. For example,

```
$redirectUrl = urlencode(base64_encode($redirectUrl));  
// a base64_encode of index.php?option=com_pizzapie' yeilds: 'aW5kZXgucGhwP29wdGlvbj1jb21fcGl6emFwaWU='
```

Prepend the '&return=' query string to your newly encoded $redirectUrl. For example,

```
$redirectUrl = '&return='.$redirectUrl;
```

Append that $redirectUrl to the Joomla Login Url. For example,

```
$joomlaLoginUrl = 'index.php?option=com_users&view=login';
$finalUrl = $joomlaLoginUrl . $redirectUrl;
```

When you display that $finalUrl, it should look something like this: 'index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=aW5kZXgucGhwP29wdGlvbj1jb21fcGl6emFwaWU='

The controller.php file in the com_users checks the contents of the 'return' in the JRequest object (the Joomla query access object). If it is set and in the base64 format, it base64_decode(s) it and applies that redirection.